# How to change the color of a single word in a sentence in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Text(
  "This is the sentence and "This one" have to be in different color",
  style:TextStyle (
  color: Colors.green
  ),
),
```

//How to change only "This one" in green

Answer (score 11):

You can Use `RichText` **Widget** to achieve this result.

You Can study learn more about this widget [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html)

*Below is a sample `code` from the same link*

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    text: 'Hello ',
    style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
    children: <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(text: 'bold', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      TextSpan(text: ' world!'),
    ],
  ),
)
```